# Media query isnt working

Tags: css

That menu is not responsive . It appears outside the condition.

```
@media only screen and (min-width : 320px) and (max-width : 568px) {
   .menu {
    background: transparent url(menu.png) no-repeat;
    display: inline-block;
    visibility:visible;
  }

.menu {
        background: transparent url(menu.png) no-repeat;
        display: none;
        visibility:hidden;   
    }
```

Comment: you forget to close @media {**}**

Comment: specificity issue, bad syntax, etc etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First

```
.menu {
        background: transparent url(menu.png) no-repeat;
        display: none;
        visibility:hidden;   
    }
```

Then

```
@media only screen and (min-width : 320px) and (max-width : 568px) {
   .menu {
    background: transparent url(menu.png) no-repeat;
    display: inline-block;
    visibility:visible;
  } }
```

Comment: oh no.. CSS have the top down approach..

Comment: @DadhichSourav media query shold be below the main css properties.